# Why a npgsql query get a different now value as direct server query

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure in postgres using .net and Npgsql to return now() value.

Running from .net

```
strSQL = "select aa_realtime2();"
cmd = New NpgsqlCommand(strSQL, connRead)
strSQL = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

I get "2014-04-07 22:07:33.015+02"

But if I run from server

```
select aa_realtime2();
```

I get "2014-04-07 15:38:11.734-04:30"

My local time is gmt -4:30 so the server is ok.

Postgres and .net app are on the same pc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me both values look like a very similar time just given in different time zones.

I'd like to quote from http://www.depesz.com/2014/04/04/how-to-deal-with-timestamps/ because it discusses a similar issue.

> […]
>   Well, whenever dealing with timestamptz values, if the timezone is not
>   specified – PostgreSQL uses configured timezone.
>
> And you can configure it in multiple ways:
>
> ```
> timezone “GUC" in postgresql.conf
> alter database … set timezone = ‘…'
> alter user … set timezone = ‘…'
> SET timezone = ‘…'
> ```
>
> First one is used to specify in which timezone your server is. Or –
>   the default timezone that will be used unless something else changes
>   the default.
>
> The next two change defaults for given database and user.
>
> The last one can be used if you want your db connection to work under
>   different setting.
>   […]

Is it possible that your database connections simply use different time zones?

Comment: Thanks. Both sentence can solve the issue. A) Setting the timezone inside the store proc or B) alter user … set timezone = ‘…'

Answer (score 1):

Most client drivers like PgJDBC, nPgSQL, etc, will work in UTC, and expect you to convert to/from UTC within your application. So they'll set the `TimeZone` session variable to `UTC`.

By contrast, `psql` by default leaves `TimeZone` at the server default, which is the timezone of the operating system.

If you want a local time from a query in .net, I recommend using the `AT TIME ZONE` operator to explicitly convert the time zone. Or fetch the date in UTC and do the timezone conversion with .net client-side code.